# Pulling data-caption from image with Elastic Image Slideshow, and display it on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [Elastic Image Slideshow](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/21/elastic-image-slideshow-with-thumbnail-preview/) script, and would like to add data-caption text for each image, then display the text of the currently shown image into a div, outside of the slideshow (basically in a different section of the page.)

I found [this script](http://blog.fraser-hart.co.uk/add-captions-to-jquery-cycle/), to work with jQuery cycle, and tried to modify it to work but I am not having much luck.

Ok, I found this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Snfst/6/ and modified it down to this:

```
   $('img').hover(function(){
      $('#caption').html($(this).data('caption'))
   });
```

Question now is how do I get it to load without having to hover over the image, and only show the data for the currently shown image?

The page that I'm trying to make this work on might better show what I'm trying to do:
http://diguiseppi.com/Brad/Andy/portfolio-web-design.html

Comment: Anyone? Normally I'll ask a question and someone knows the answer in a matter of hours...

Comment: Can anyone answer this, or know a good tutorial to read?